# Rails test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am very new to testing in Rails. I am attempting to create a very basic test for the index action in my albums controller. I am getting an error, not jsut on this test, but on all of my tests. The error looks like this:

```
bin/rails test test/controllers/albums_controller_test.rb:18

E

Error:
AlbumsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraintfailed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-01-11 21:54:05.906006', '2017-01-11 21:54:05.906006', 298486374)
```

All of my tests get this error, not just this one. This is the test I was attempting to run with the above example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AlbumTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
test "index action should work" do
 get :index
 assert_response :success
end
end
```

Here is the index action in my albums controller:

```
def index
  @albums = Album.all.order(year: :desc).order(title: :asc)
end
```

Not sure what's going on. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you edit with `albums_controller_test.rb` code

Answer (score 0):

I would need some more code to give a better solution, but by the error it seems that you are trying to create more than one user with the same email. And since you are validating them to be UNIQUE, than the test fails.

So I think the problem must be somewhere else where you create the users for the test.

If you're using fixtures, you can try something like this:

```
john:
    name: $LABEL
    email: $LABEL@example.com
```

And if you are using factory girl, you can try something like this:

```
factory :user do
    name              "John"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@example.com" }
```

Hope it helps..